# can you reuse code in different flows? in Precess Maker V4

Tags: processmaker

is it possible with version 4 of process maker to reuse code for different flows?
Can you have common variables, triggers, etc for each process you perform?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the scripts you define can be used in any process. There is no constraint between the script and the processes you can use it in.
You can also define environment variables wich should be accessible from everywhere (i have not used them yet)